# Is there an OData producer (server) in Python?

Tags: python, odata

I'm looking to expose a series of Pandas dataframes for consumption via OData. Is there a python library that implements the entire OData functionality?

Comment: A quick search on pypi shows [this library](https://pypi.org/project/odata-server/) as an option. You can browse through other pypi packages if it doesn't meet your need